# How IIFE and eventListeners work togheter?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a weather app in js vanilla for exercise in functional programming.

In the home page you have a simple input tag where you put the name of the city you want to have the forecasts. When you hit the enter button the IIFE (in the snippet) gets fired and actually starts the entire app.

Now I have some questions related to that IIFE because it works but I'm not really sure of how that code actually work (and maybe it is written with a bad baaaad baaaaaaaad practice):

how does IIFE knows that a key is being un-pressed? Ok, I have registered an event on the input tag but it is written inside the IIFE. So how the IIFE knows that an event has been fired? I mean, I'm not passing any event to that function. The registration of the event shouldn't that be a step before (out of) the IIFE?

I think it's clear that I'm a little confused.

```js
(() => {
 const input =      document.querySelector('.banner__input');
  input.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log('The city is: ' + input.value);
      currentWeather();
      threeHoursForecasts();
      toggleForecasts();
    } 
  });
})();
```

```html
And this is the input tag:

<input type="text" class="banner__input" value="Milan" autofocus onfocus="this.value = this.value;">
```

Comment: The only IIFE you have in your code, has nothing todo with the event listener...

Comment: The question is not clear. Your IIFE does side effects by selecting inputs from the DOM and adding event listenters to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How IIFE and eventListeners work togheter?

They more or less do not.

An IIFE in this context does nothing except provide a scope for local variables and constants (in this case `input`) to exist in.

The only thing the IIFE does is prevent `const input` from becoming a global.

---

> how does IIFE knows that a key is being un-pressed?

It doesn't.

When the keyup event fires, the function that is bound as the event listener is called by the browser.

The IIFE has already run by that stage. All that is left of it is the scope.

> Ok, I have registered an event on the input tag

Yes

> but it is written inside the IIFE

Not really relevant.

> So how the IIFE knows that an event has been fired?

It doesn't. The event handler function you passed to `addEventListner` is called by the browser.

> I mean, I'm not passing any event to that function.

No, the browser passes the event.

Comment: Very detailed answear, you cleared all my doubts. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

> how does IIFE knows that a key is being un-pressed? Ok, I have registered an event on the input tag but it is written inside the IIFE. So how the IIFE knows that an event has been fired? I mean, I'm not passing any event to that function. The registration of the event shouldn't that be a step before (out of) the IIFE?

The IIFE doesn't know anything about th event. It's just a function that runs immediately and then exits. So it simply runs the code in its body, and that's all.

The event handler is the only thing concerned with the event.

```
event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log('The city is: ' + input.value);
    currentWeather();
    threeHoursForecasts();
    toggleForecasts();
  } 
}
```

This is the function you passed to `.addEventListener`. Internally, it becomes associated with the `input` element so the event system can invoke it when that event occurs.

---

Note that you do not need an IIFE here. You can reference the `input` using `this` or `event.currentTarget`.

```
document.querySelector('.banner__input')
  .addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log('The city is: ' + this.value);
      currentWeather();
      threeHoursForecasts();
      toggleForecasts();
    }   
  });
```

---

Also note that even if you did want to keep a reference to `input` or something else, you still don't need an IIFE. You can just use a *block-statement* as long as you use `let` or `const` to declare the variable.

```
{ // The `input` is scoped to this block
  const input = document.querySelector('.banner__input');

  input.addEventListener("keyup", event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log('The city is: ' + input.value);
      currentWeather();
      threeHoursForecasts();
      toggleForecasts();
    }   
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When you hit the enter button the IIFE (in the snippet) gets fired

No. The IIFE is invoked - as its name says - immediately when the script is loaded. In fact the IIFE is not necessary at all, you could simply have written

```
document.querySelector('.banner__input').addEventListener("keyup", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    console.log('The city is: ' + this.value);
    currentWeather();
    threeHoursForecasts();
    toggleForecasts();
  } 
});
```

with exactly the same effect.

> How does IIFE knows that a key is being un-pressed? Ok, I have registered an event on the input tag but it is written inside the IIFE.

The IIFE doesn't know. The callback function that you passed to `addEventListener` will - that is the one that will get called. `addEventListener` is doing the registration stuff.

> I mean, I'm not passing any event to that function.

Yes, the `event` does come from the DOM when the event happens.